# android studio calculation program in kotlin

Tags: android

```
fun main(v: View){
    var a: Int = editText1.text.toString().toInt()
    var b: String = editText2.text.toString()
    var c: Int = editText3.text.toString().toInt()

    textView.text = calculate(a, b, c).toString()
}

fun calculate(a: Int, b: String, c: Int) =
    when (b) {
        "+" -> a + c
        "-" -> a - c
        "*" -> a * c
        "/" -> a / c
        else -> "다시 입력하세요"
    }
```

}

*(Android) xml file with 3 edittexts and 1 button, then id is edittext1, 2, 3 / button
I created a textView (id = textView) to represent this result.
I expressed the main function as onClick in the xml file but it doesn't work ㅠㅠㅠ*

> (안드로이드)  xml 파일에 edittext 3개와 버튼 1개 차례대로 id는 edittext1, 2, 3 / button 이라고 해놓고 
>                이 결과를 표현할 textView(id= textView)를 만들었습니다.
>                main 함수를 xml파일내 onClick으로 표현해줬는데 작동이 안되네요ㅠㅠㅠ

Comment: @dangdang please add description in English language

Answer (score 1):

you need to return the value of the calculate method

```
fun calculate(a: Int, b: String, c: Int):Int? =
    when (b) {
        "+" -> a + c
        "-" -> a - c
        "*" -> a * c
        "/" -> a / c
        else -> null
    }
```